# OpenMP: 2 Nested For loops inside of a While loop. How to fix for multi-threaded functionality? (Jacobi Solver)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm attempting to parallelize a Jacobi grid solver using OpenMP.

When 1 thread is used:

As it stands, the code executes correctly when only a single thread is assigned, and produces the same results as a reference single-threaded function (not shown).
The while loop breaks when the difference variable is less than "0.01000"(as it should)

When two or more threads are used:

The code runs through the outer while loop only once.
The difference value from the first thread is way above 0.0100 (as it should be), but the difference value given by the other thread(s) is below it instantaneously, so the loop breaks, without doing any of the calculations.

I've tested a lot compilation iterations of strategically placing respective variables in either the shared/private/reduction clauses hoping to get the diff value to accumulate correctly over all threads used. I get that the "diff" variable should be shared by all threads, but what I've tried has not worked to accumulate the values from all threads. I'm not sure what else I can try?

Thanks for your time and input

```
int 
compute_using_omp_jacobi (grid_t *grid, int num_threads)
    {

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  int i, j;
  int num_iter = 0;
    int done = 0;

    double diff;
    float old, new; 
  float eps = 1e-2; /* Convergence criteria. */
  int num_elements; 


omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);

#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(grid, eps, done, diff) private ( i, j, old, new, num_elements) reduction (+:num_iter)




    while(!done) { /* While we have not converged yet. */
    diff = 0.0;
  num_elements = 0;

#pragma omp for reduction (+: diff) collapse(2)
        for (i = 1; i < (grid->dim - 1); i++) 

            for (j = 1; j < (grid->dim - 1); j++) {
                old = grid->element[i * grid->dim + j]; /* Store old value of grid point. */
                /* Apply the update rule. */    
                new = 0.25 * (grid->element[(i - 1) * grid->dim + j] +\
                              grid->element[(i + 1) * grid->dim + j] +\
                              grid->element[i * grid->dim + (j + 1)] +\
                              grid->element[i * grid->dim + (j - 1)]);

                grid->element[i * grid->dim + j] = new; /* Update the grid-point value. */
                diff = diff + fabs(new - old); /* Calculate the difference in values. */
                num_elements++;
                 //printf ("DIFF %f.", diff);
            }


        /* End of an iteration. Check for convergence. */
        diff = diff/num_elements;
        printf ("Iteration %d. DIFF: %f.\n", num_iter, diff);
//        printf ("number of elements %d.", num_elements);


        num_iter++;

        if (diff < eps) 
            done = 1;
    }

    return num_iter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parallelize the `while` loop, since the values for `grid->element` in each iteration depend on the values from the previous iteration.

You'll have to move the `#pragma omp parallel` inside the while (to before the first `for` loop).

`num_elements` should be named in the `reduction` clause, and `new` and `old` should be declared *within* the body of the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! I moved the  1st #pragma statement to inside of the while loop, and added num_elem to the reduction clause, and the script works, and my headache is gone.